# If the Additive Subgroup of a Ring is Cyclic, is the Multiplicative Identity Necessarily a Generator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Here's a question that I've thought of, but have had trouble proving/disproving. If a ring $R$ is additively cyclic, then does $1_R$ necessarily generate the additive group of $R$? I cannot think of any counterexamples.